# How do I get the identity column's value after INSERT?

Tags: r, sql-server, sql-server-2012, rodbc

I am trying to use R's `RODBC` library to insert into a table `tbl` in SQL SERVER 2012 which has an identity column. I do my insert as follows:

```
INSERT INTO tbl(col1, col2, col3)
VALUES (1, 2, 3)
```

and then I would like to get the identity column's value. I know I need to do `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` but I don't know how to make that work. Here is what I tried:

```
library(RODBC)
query.str <- "
              INSERT INTO tbl(col1, col2, col3)
              VALUES (1, 2, 3);
              SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
             "
some.return <- sqlQuery(dbcon, query.str)
```

`some.return` doesn't have any value. I was hoping the output of `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` would be there... Any ideas on how to get the identity value?

Comment: I wonder if there is some way in RODBC to execute multiple queries and grab the result of the last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work in a somewhat dirty way. I'm not sure if this is the only way of doing this - I don't like to issue 2 statements to sql server since this can be risky in a parallel environment... But as a solution this does seems to work:

```
library(RODBC)

#semicolon at the end of the sql seems significant
query.str <- "
              INSERT INTO tbl(col1, col2, col3)
              VALUES (1, 2, 3);
             "
output <- sqlQuery(dbcon, query.str)
if (is.character(output) && length(output) > 0)
  stop(paste("SQL ERROR: ", output))

reg.id <- sqlQuery(dbcon, "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()")
if (is.character(reg.id) && length(reg.id) > 0)
  stop(paste("SQL ERROR: ", reg.id))

reg.id[[1]]
```